# What are some advanced troubleshooting approaches for message passing in Chrome Extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've got a Chrome Extension where the popup messages the content script - pretty straightforward. The following works consistently on macOS (Chrome 61.0.3164.100) but not on Windows 10 (Chrome 61.0.3163.100):

**aSearch.js (popup)**

```
function sendMessage(comment){
  window.close();   //Close popup.
  console.log("In send message: " + comment);

  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "insertComment", comment: comment}, function(response) {
          // console.log(response.farewell);
      });
  });

}
```

**Then content.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('In content script after receiving request to insertcomment...');

    if (request.method == 'insertComment'){
etc...
```

I can provide a lot more code...but the "console.log" does not fire even though background.js shows the related activity.

The aSearch.js is for an html popup that replaces the initial one...after you log in (not sure if this is important). This is accomplished in background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({   //Sets popup to last visited
popup: 'aSearch.html'   // Open this html file within the popup.
});
```

Any guidance on what can make messaging break? Should I be taking a different approach for a constant (frequent) messaging that is used across many tabs, potentially?

Why would Chrome for Windows act differently?

Side note: I actually updated Chrome for Windows as I wrote this question...after the update suddenly messaging worked, for a little bit, then went back to dormant.

UPDATING QUESTION:
I added more code to the aSearch.js popup at the top...

I think I'm closing the popup before the message can be sent...and it's working sometimes (and on my macOS dev machine) because the computer is fast. On Windows, which is VM on my mac, not so fast...

Tomorrow I'll move the close inside the response from messaging...waiting for message to reply.

Is this plausible?

Comment: Make sure the content script is actually loaded. For example add console.log at the beginning of the file or debug it in devtools - Sources - Content scripts.

Comment: It is - because I’ve got a focusin listener that had a console msg. Thx for looking!

Comment: I did not answer it - I commented on it to clarify that I know my content.js script is loaded on the page.

Comment: Well, there's no way to answer the question based on the information it contains. The posted code should work and it works so obviously there's something else going on.

Comment: Fair enough...and that is helpful by itself. I changed the title to focus on the real question: how do I troubleshoot messaging, specifically a content script that doesn't 'hear' a sent message - but only on Windows, not macOS.

Comment: I added a bit more code and the potential root cause. Will test more thoroughly tomorrow. If you think I’m on the right track (closing pop up too soon) please let me know.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was, indeed, that you can't close a popup window before the message is successfully sent.

Duh.

The challenge, though, is that on my machines the message is sent successfully before the window closes. So I didn't discover the bug.

I have the message receiver acknowledging success and then closing the popup. Works like a charm.